# Reading a list, splitting it, then making it into 3 new lists

Tags: python

I have a file that includes a list of every zip code, city, and state in the US. When I read a list it looks like " `'00501', 'Huntsville', 'NY'` ".

So what I'm trying to do in Python is:

Open the file, read everysingle line, split the lines, then create 3 new lists Zip, City, State and place all the data from the original list into the new lists.

So far, I have the following code:

```
def main():
   zipcode = []
   city = []
   state = []

   file_object = open("zipcodes.txt", "r")
   theList = file_object.readlines()
   splitlist = theList.split(',')

   zipcode.append(splitlist[0])
   city.append(splitlist[1])
   state.append(splitlist[2])

   file_object.close()
```

Comment: Please show how the data in your file is formatted. The "list" you've shown us looks like a string, not like a list, so it's hard to give a useful answer. Also, please include your code in the question. We expect help seekers to make an attempt to solve the problem on their own.

Comment: There's no particular part of what you want to do that's at all hard to translate from pseudocode into Python (except maybe for dealing with edge cases on those quoted strings, which `csv.reader` out of the stdlib will do for you automatically). So, what part are you having trouble writing?

Comment: Hints: to open a file, call `open`. To do something for every single line in a file, that's `for line in file`. To split a line, that's `line.split` (although again, you may want to consider `for line in csv.reader(file)`). To create three new lists out of one list of 3-lists, that's `z, c, s = zip(rows)`.

Comment: pretty simple i guess, show us your code

Comment: Hi Nick, I have taken your comment and edited your question - try not to post pictures but rather the actual code; and the area below is reserved for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have the basics, you are just missing a loop so the process repeats for each line in the file:

```
theList = file_object.readlines()
for line in theList:
   splitlist = line.split(',')

   zipcode.append(splitlist[0])
   city.append(splitlist[1])
   state.append(splitlist[2])
```

Keep in mind that `readlines()` returns the *entire file* so your `theList` contains the entire file's contents. You just have to loop over it.

Here is a different version you can try:

```
def main():

   zips = []
   cities = []
   states = []

   with open('zipcodes.txt', 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
         bits = line.split(',')
         zips.append(bits[0])
         cities.append(bits[1])
         states.append(bits[2])
```

The `with_statement` is a way to read files. It ensures that files are automatically closed.

The `for line in f:` loop is what you were missing in your code - this will go through each line.

The body of the for loop is exactly what you have written, so that part you had down well.